# Create VM from template , Hostname issue

Tags: rhel, vmware, hostname, template

I created a VM from RHEL ISO Fle, and followed some steps to cleanup nic details and also inserted a systemd script to create machine id. Converted VM to template, However when i spin a new VM with new hostname  via template, it has same Hostname as template.
Can you please direct what i missed here, I went through lot of documents found online nothing helped me out. New to VMware world.Thanks

Comment: So you believe that your systemd script did not run? Or ran but did not change the system id? Or what? Could you post the unit file and script and the resulting status?

Comment: @ Jeff Schaller I followed this document it did change system Id, and created new one however the host name is same as template.... https://hakuna.cloud/blog/cloning_vm_in_vcenter.html

Comment: My mistake, I was stuck on the systemd / system id part. I think hostnames should be set during installation, not during cloning. How would a template know what hostname you wanted ahead of time? Do you set a hostname and it gets reverted?

Comment: @Jeff Schaller  yes when i set while creating a vm from template, it gets reverted  yes

Comment: perhaps you could spell out the steps you take, in as much detail as you can -- summarize the VM cloning steps and the boot process, then the steps you take to set the hostname, followed by the result.